# Mp3 File in multiple subgenres without being duplicated. Is that possible?

Tags: mp3, metadata, structure, id3

I am writing a script at the moment which takes ID3 metadata from mp3 files and grabs genre (for example "electronic") and subgenre (for example "Industrial, Idm, Ambient etc). After that, it moves those mp3s in genre/subgenre.

When subgenre is only one there is no problem but, if number of subgenres is greater than one then i will have 2 or more same mp3s in separate folders.

Folder Structure

- Music

  - Genre

    - Electronic

      - Industrial (x.mp3)
      - Ambient (x.mp3)
      - Uk Garage (x.mp3)

        etc

This mp3 in multiple folders means more data. Also, if i decide to sacrifice data and keep this in multiple folders , any analyze (bpm count, grid placement etc) will exist only in one of those mp3s.

---

**So, How can i avoid this?**

A possible solution to my problem would be shortcuts but, many applications such as Traktor or Ableton do not recognize shortcuts in their browser. Is there any solution for that?

Another solution would be , keeping mp3 in multiple folders but linking their data somehow.

Finally, I am not familiar with server folder structure or databases but i imagine there are several folder structures for helping search methods in servers to avoid data waste. Is this relative to my problem?  :) 
Thanks

**EDIT**

Currently I am working on Windows 8 Dual booting with Ubuntu Studio. I have a shared Ntfs Partition And I would like to have this folder structure accessible in both operating systems But for now I want to prepare this for Windows And After that In Linux.

**EDIT 2**

I Have completed my script but i have a problem. I have defined this function:

```
def album_Linker(album_path, album_Genre, album_Style):
genre_basedir = "E:\Music\#02.Genre"
artist_basedir = "E:\Music\#03.Artist"
release_data_basedir = "E:\Music\#04.ReleaseDate"
for genre in os.listdir(genre_basedir):
    genre_path = os.path.join(genre_basedir, "_" + album_Genre)
    if not os.path.isdir(genre_path):
        os.mkdir(genre_path)
    album_Style_list = album_Style.split(', ')
    print album_Style_list
    for style in album_Style_list:
        style_path = os.path.join(genre_path, "_" + style)
        if not os.path.isdir(style_path):
            os.mkdir(style_path)
        album_path_list = album_path.split("_")
        print album_path_list
        #link_dst = unicode(os.path.join(style_path, album_path_list[2] + "_" + album_path_list[1] + "_" + album_path_list[0]))
        link_dst = unicode(os.path.join(style_path, album_path))
        link_src = unicode(album_path)
        kdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
        kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkW(link_dst, link_src, 1)
```

Firstly, it creates the symlinks only when the script is running fro cmd as administrator.
Secondly, when i am trying to double click and enter the directory from symlink i get

> Directory is not accessible.The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: What OS?  Windows?  OSX?  Linux?  On all three, you can create symlinks, but how you do it varies.

Comment: @Brad Will those Symlinks be readble and accessible through several applications' browsers ( Such as Traktor Or Ableton) ? I am not asking for those specific applications but for the differencies of shortcuts and symlinks in this matter.

Comment: Yes.  The application doesn't know or care how the underlying filesystem works.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/7109/52951

Comment: @Brad Ok, I Have Just Tested That And Works :D Very Helpfull Thanks I will complete the script and try it. After That i will post it here ! Thanks

Comment: @Brad I edited the post. I have some issues with creating symlinks. Maybe you can give me an idea of what i should do! Thanks